# Oracle Getting Records for a Month

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm having trouble with my WHERE clause when trying to retrieve records for a certain month.

```
WHERE NVL(TO_CHAR(prsl.DEADLINE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_CHAR(prsl.SUBMIT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) >= DATE '2015-11-01'
AND NVL(TO_CHAR(prsl.DEADLINE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_CHAR(prsl.SUBMIT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) < DATE '2015-12-01'
```

Basically what this does is if `DEADLINE` is not null, use that to compare to the date range. If it is null, use the `SUBMIT_DATE` for comparison instead.

Using the above query, I get this error:

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Comment: Are prsl.dealdline and prsl.submit_date DATE columns? If so, why are you doing to_char() on them and then comparing them to something that's a date?! If you want to strip off the time part from the date columns, you could just do `nvl(trunc(prsl.deadline), trunc(prsl.submit_date))`

Comment: Yes they are both DATE columns. Let me try your solution if it works.

Comment: @Boneist That worked perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you convert a `DATE` to a string and then compare this string with a date?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `EXTRACT`:

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM prsl.DEADLINE) = 11
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM prsl.DEADLINE) = 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be this:

```
WHERE TRUNC(COALESCE(prsl.DEADLINE, prsl.SUBMIT_DATE), 'MM') = DATE '2015-11-01'
```